# For each loop not looping all rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, foreach

I'm trying to loop all rows of a table name `cart` but the `foreach` is only displaying the last row entered and always ignore the previous ones. Say I have 5 products in the `cart_table` well only `product_id[5]` will be displayed. If user adds a sixth item, only `product_id[6]` will now be displayed. The `$item_count` will also always equal `1` as if there is only one item when there are multiple. To my understanding in the `foreach($items as $item)` `$items` is not seen as an array even with multiple items. when I     `var_dump($items);` it shows `array(1) { [0]=>...`

add_cart.php

```
    <?php 
ob_start();
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ecommerce/core/init.php'; 
$product_id = isset($_POST['product_id'])? sanitize($_POST['product_id']):'';
$size = isset($_POST['size'])? sanitize($_POST['size']):'';
$available = isset($_POST['available'])? sanitize($_POST['available']):'';
$quantity  = isset($_POST['quantity'])? sanitize($_POST['quantity']):'';
$item = array(); 
$item[] = array(
    'id'            => $product_id, 
    'size'         => $size, 
    'quantity' => $quantity,
    'available' => $available
    ); 
$domain =($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost')?'.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:false;
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = '{$product_id}'"); 
$product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); 
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = $product['prod_name']. ' was added to your cart.'; 

//check if the cart cookie exists
if (is_array($cart_id != ' ')) {
$cartQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'"); 
$cart = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ); 
$previous_items = json_decode($cart['items'],true); 
$item_match = 0; 
$new_items = array(); 

foreach($previous_items as $pitem){
    if ($item[0]['id'] == $pitem['id'] && $item[0]['size'] == $pitem['size']) {
        $pitem['quantity'] = $pitem['quantity'] + $item[0]['quantity']; 

if ($pitem['quantity'] > $available) {
    $pitem['quantity'] = $available; 

} 
$item_match = 1; 
} 
$new_items[] = $pitem; 
}

if ($item_match != 1) {
    $new_items = array_merge($item,$previous_items); 
} 

$items_json = json_encode($new_items); 
$cart_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+30 days")); 
$db->query("UPDATE cart SET items = '{$items_json}', expire_date = '{$cart_expire}' WHERE id = '{cart_id}'"); 
setcookie(CART_COOKIE,'',1,"/",$domain,false); 
setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false); 

}else{ 
// add to databse and set cookie
    $items_json = json_encode($item); 
    $cart_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+30 days"));
    $db->query("INSERT INTO cart (items,expire_date) VALUES ('{$items_json}','{$cart_expire}')"); 
    $cart_id = $db->insert_id; 
    setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false); 
}
?>
```

cart.php

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
//include 'includes/headerpartial.php';
if($cart_id != ' ') {
    $cartQ      = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id ='{$cart_id}' ");
    $result     = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ);
    $items      = json_decode($result['items'], true);
    $i          = 1;
    $sub_total  = 0;
    $item_count = 0;
}
?>
<?php if($cart_id == ' '): ?>
    <div class="bg-danger">
        <p class='text-center text-danger'>Your cart is empty.</p>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        var_export($items);
        $product_id   = $item['id'];
        $productQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id ='{$product_id}' ");
        $product      = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productQuery);
        $sArray       = explode(',', $product['sizes']);

/*      foreach ($sArray as $sizeString) {
            $s = explode(':', $sizeString);
            if($s[0] == $item['size']) {
                $available = $s[1];
            }
        }*/

        ?>

        <tr class="p">
            <td class="image"><img src="<?= $product['image_1']; ?>"/></td>
            <td class="name"><?= $product['prod_name']; ?></td>
            <td class="price"><?= money($product['price']); ?></td>
            <td class="quantity"><?= $item['quantity']; ?></td>
            <td class="pricesubtotal"><?= money($item['quantity'] * $product['price']); ?></td>
            <td class="remove">
                <div>&times</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $i ++;
        $item_count += $item['quantity'];
        $sub_total += ($product['price'] * $item['quantity']);

    }
    $tax         = TAXRATE * $sub_total;
    $tax         = number_format($tax, 2);
    $grand_total = $tax + $sub_total;

     <?php      endif;?>
```

Comment: Can you show the entire code? After quickly glancing over what you're showing the issue might be from previous code.

Comment: which foreach are you talking about? The child one or the parent?

Comment: The last line of your "displayed" code needs to be endif; ?> as you are missing an endif: if that is where the code actually ends within that if statement.

Comment: Can you show the results of $result['items']. Maybe the json data is not correctly formatted

Comment: @TimBrownlaw: That is not where the code ends but for the purpose of this post I added the endif.

Comment: @McStuffins: Which foreach? There's only one loop statement here?

Comment: You commented out the child, can you show $items in a var_dump()?

Comment: @DillonGilmore: You probably meant to see the add_cart.php so I added the page.

Comment: @McStuffins:     `$items = json_decode($result['$items'], true);var_dump($items);` I got NULL when there are 3 items in the cart at the moment.

Comment: @McStuffins: ok that is strange I got NULL as well. There is something going on with the query im guessing

Comment: I guess.hope debugging helped.

Comment: @McStuffins: I'm lowkey beginner in PHP if you don't mind I have one more question to help me fix this. If I can add and see the products on the table when visiting localhost/phpmyadmin, how is the query affecting the display on the cart.php?

Comment: What is the type of id in phpmyadmin? I have a feeling that it would not be a string. Please check.

Comment: If you have any other problems, feel free to email me @ mcstuffins99 @ outlook.com

Comment: I think i know the problem. The data is not being inserted into MySQL properly because you are trying to insert JSON. JSON is not able to be inserted into MySQL because MySQL uses Quotes for Syntax.

Comment: @McStuffins: id type is autoincrement integer

Comment: you've cut and pasted a whole lot of irrelevant code, but managed to exclude any clue as to what $db is.

Comment: @symcbean: Well thanks for the downvote bro! Anyone with a bit of experience in Php would know that $db is the mysqli_connect to the database. It wouldn't be relevant to past the whole init.php... Unlesss you explain why you think it would?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the problems. You told me that your `id` is an auto increment int, so I would like to propose this answer. The problem is in your sql command.

```
UPDATE cart SET items = '{$items_json}', expire_date = '{$cart_expire}' WHERE id = {cart_id}
```

Be sure to put that command in quotes. Also, I highly recommend preparing the JSON with this command:

```
$itemJson = addslashes($itemJson);
```

then, you can run the command. Another possibility would be to use the prepare method from mysqli. Here is a link to some examples:

[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

if you have any further questions, feel free to update your question, but be sure to @McStuffins in the comments.